# Will Gmail render any font used in an amp-email?

Tags: gmail, amp-html, webfonts, amp-email

Normally, GMail clients have very limited web font support, unlike their Apple Mail and Outlook counterparts. (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/)

If one uses amp-email, however - would GMail render any web font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [amp-email documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/email-spec/amp-email-css/#custom-fonts-(@font-face)), custom fonts are **not** supported.